Authorize HeadBucket request
I would like to use HeadBucket to get the region of some buckets. The following request,
curl -v --head https://s3hub.s3.amazonaws.com

gets indeed the region but yields 400 error. Considering standard signed requests require the bucket region, is there a way to authorize this request and have 200 response?
P. S. there is also GetBucketLocation but the reference recommends using HeadBucket.
EDIT: I tried to send a signed HeadBucket request with Postman. When I provided the correct region I got 200; with any different region (e.g. us-east-1) I got 400 error.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781692/what-is-the-headbucket-operation-in-amazon-s3

As noted in the documentation, you need s3:ListBucket permission.  You can sign a send a HeadBucket request to any region (us-east-1 is common, but any region will work).  The response will give you a HTTP 301 redirect, which you can follow up with and use the correct region, or simply use that information.

You might also consider using the awscli: aws s3api head-bucket.

@AnonCoward I tried with Postman and I got 200 by providing the correct region in the signature; with the wrong region I got 400 error, no 301 error.
